# Not able to execute sql insertion from _mysql python package

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert a query to a Mysql table using _mysql package of python. The query I wrote is:

```
que = '''insert into all_prices(date,market,commodity,variety,arrival,Minimum_Price,Maximum_Price,Modal_Price,source,state)values('''+str(a)+''','''+market_name+''','''+commodity+''','''+variety+''','''+arrival+''','''+Min_Price+''','''+Max_Price+''','''+Modal_Price+''','''+'''delagrimarket,delhi)'''

db.query(que)
```

one of the value of que is:

```
que = insert into all_prices(date,market,commodity,variety,arrival,Minimum_Price,Maximum_Price,Modal_Price,source,state)values(1,azadpur,Apple,Royal Delicious,899,6000,11000,8200,delagrimarket,delhi)
```

but I am getting some error like:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Delicious,899,6000,11000,8200,delagrimarket,delhi)' at line 1")
```

Can someone please help in solving this query.

Comment: wrap each values in between `''` like `('value1','value2')`

Comment: I answered the question thinking it was for PHP.  I deleted the answer that I posted. As far as mysql is concered, the values must be wrapped between `''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
que = '''
insert into
all_prices
(date, market, commodity, variety, arrival, Minimum_Price, Maximum_Price, Modal_Price, source, state)
values('{0}', '{1}', {2}, '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', 'delagrimarket', 'delhi')'''
.format(str(a), market_name, commodity, variety, arrival, Min_Price, Max_Price, Modal_Price)
db.query(que)
```

A cleaner approach would be:

```
vals = (str(a), market_name, commodity, variety, arrival, Min_Price, Max_Price, Modal_Price)
que = '''
insert into
all_prices
(date, market, commodity, variety, arrival, Minimum_Price, Maximum_Price, Modal_Price, source, state)
values('{0}', '{1}', {2}, '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', 'delagrimarket', 'delhi')
'''
db.query(que.format(*vals))
```

The second approach is very useful if you want to execute the same query multiple times with different values.

Check this out for more information about string.format https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format

Answer (score 0):

Better use string formatting something similar like this

```
que = '''insert into all_prices(date,market,commodity,variety,arrival,Minimum_Price,Maximum_Price,Modal_Price,source,state)values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''
vals = (str(a), market_name, commodity, variety, arrival, Min_Price, Max_Price, Modal_Price, "delagrimarket", "delhi")
con.query(que % values)
```

For more information about string formatting look at the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).